# Is it possible to request only part of a string in Firestore?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I have string fields in Firestore that can be quite long. Sometimes, all I need is the first X characters of that field and don't need the entire string. Is there a way to tell Firestore to only give me a substring of the field instead of the entire thing every time?

EDIT: This is not a question of text search, I'm try to get just the first X characters of a field, I'm not searching anything. I'm trying to minimize the data that Firestore sends back in order to minimize cost and bandwidth. Similar to `SELECT LEFT(field , 100) FROM myTable` in MySQL to get just the first 100 characters of `field`.

Comment: Firestore does not offer substring queries.  You can do string prefixes though.

Comment: @DougStevenson This is not a question of substring search. I've edited with a (hopefully) clarified explanation.

Comment: It's not possible to get a partial field value in query results. Your query will always retrieve the entire field.